# Object Item does not support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, compiler-errors

So, I'm a beginner when it comes to VBA, but I'm trying to create a simple way to send a reminder message to a bunch of people whose information is found on an excel spreadsheet. It is supposed to loop, sending emails to addresses found in the column until there is an empty cell.

I keep getting the error `Object does not support this property or method` on the line that begins with a *. I have spent the last hour trying to figure out why this error is appearing because `Workbooks` have the property `Sheets` which have `Cells` which return a value.

```
Sub Send_Reminder_Email()

    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim xlApp As Object, wb As Object
    Dim row As Integer

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\User\Me\...file.xls")
    row = 2

    *Do While Not IsEmpty(wb.Sheets.Cells(row, 2).Value)
        objMsg.To = wb.Sheets.Cells(row, 6)
        objMsg.BCC = "potapeno@foo.net"
        objMsg.Subject = "Email"
        objMsg.Body = "Information"
        objMsg.Send
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    row = 0

End Sub
```

I have also tried "activating" the workbook, but it fails to solve my problem. I can't figure out what object doesn't support what method.

Comment: `wb.Sheets` is a collection and doesn't have `.Cells` property. Specify the worksheet e. g. `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value`

Comment: Please write in an answer so I can call this question answered. But thanks, I swear I tried that and it didn't work, but it is now working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wb.Sheets` is a collection and doesn't have `.Cells` property. You can explore methods and properties with Object Browser pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> in VBA Project. Enter class name and press Search button:

[image: Object Browser]

To get a certain Worksheet object you have to specify the item of the worksheets collection e. g. by worksheet name:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(wb.Sheets.Item("Sheets1").Cells(row, 2).Value)
```

It may be not quite obvious that `.Item()` is a default property, but so it is, thus you can call it in reduced form:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(row, 2).Value)
```

Or by worksheet index:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 2).Value)
```